# Xamarin.Android Layout label not showing

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I have multiple layouts (windows) with an activity for each one of them.

There is this head label with the app name in it usually, but you can change the text in the Activity.cs by putting `[Activity(Label = "Any title")]` at the start of the Activity.

My problem is that this label only shows up in the main_activity.xml layout on my mobile device when I am testing the programme, but not in any other new created layouts, even though it shows it as a preview in the XML editor.

Is there a way to make this label show up? It isn't so that the text in the label is just the same color as the label, because my buttons etc. which I put at the top are also when testing directly at the top, there is no gap.

I open the layouts via

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, typeof(MyActivity));
StartActivity(intent);
```

which is in a button click event handler in the previous activity.

Thanks for help!

Comment: Are you adding a Toolbar to the layout yourself, or is it part of your theme?

Comment: @Cheesebaron It is part of the theme, but I know the answer now thanks to the answer below. But maybe you can tell me if there is a way to color this label in e.g. a hex color?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When i created a new Activity to load the new layout, the title would not show until i changed the `Activity` to `AppCompatActivity`.

Change:

```
 public class Activity1 : Activity
 {
 }
```

To:

```
using AndroidX.AppCompat.App;

public class  Activity1 : AppCompatActivity
{
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that fixed it! But do you know if there is a way to set the head label to a specific color like with a hex code?

Comment: You need to create a custom toolbar with specific color of head label to replace the action bar. Please check the link below. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/user-interface/controls/tool-bar/replacing-the-action-bar